# I want to simulate the antenna pointing error when tracking LEO satellites

Tags: orbital-mechanics, low-earth-orbit, tracking, simulation, space-track

I am trying to simulate the antenna pointing error of our antenna when tracking LEO satellites using TLE data. I am using the Skyfield library in python. First I loaded the TLE data from the Celestrak website, then selected the satellite from the TLE's. Next, I found the satellite passes with respect to my antenna location. Finally, I calculated the azimuth and elevation angles from the antenna to the satellite. Now the next step which I don't know how to do is to simulate a satellite pass with my own antenna following it. Because my antenna only has a rotating speed of 1.75°/sec in azimuth and elevation directions, some passes require a faster angle speed than this, for example, 5°/sec. Therefore the antenna will be left behind. I want to simulate and see how many degrees my antenna will be left behind using its speed of 1.75°/sec.  If someone could give me suggestions it would be very much welcome Thank you
This is the code I used, which is mostly from the Skyfield documentation.

```
from astropy import units as u
from skyfield.api import Topos, load
from skyfield.api import EarthSatellite

# Load earth and time
planets = load('de421.bsp')
earth = planets['earth']

ts = load.timescale()
t0 = ts.now()

# loading TLE files from celestrak

stations_url = 'https://www.celestrak.com/NORAD/elements/active.txt'
satellites = load.tle_file(stations_url, reload=False)
print('Loaded', len(satellites), 'satellites')

# Selecting Astrocast 0.2 from the TLE Dataset

by_name = {sat.name: sat for sat in satellites}
satellite = by_name['ASTROCAST 0.2']
print(satellite)

# Finding rising and setting times

antenna_position = Topos(47.01452, 8.30613, elevation_m=500)
t1 = ts.utc(2020, 12, 17)
t, events = satellite.find_events(antenna_position, t0, t1, altitude_degrees=0.0)
for ti, event in zip(t, events):
    name = ('rise above horizon', 'culminate', 'set below horizon')[event]
    print(ti.utc_strftime('%Y %b %d %H:%M:%S'), name)
# Calculating Azimuth and Elevation with regard to antenna position

difference = satellite - antenna_position
topocentric = difference.at(t0)
alt, az, distance = topocentric.altaz()

if alt.degrees > 0:
    print('The', satellite.name, 'is above the horizon')
else:
    #print(the time remaining until the next pass)
    pass

print('elevation =', alt)
print('azimuth =', az)
print(int(distance.km), 'km')

# Creating an antenna at antenna_position with an angle rotating speed of 1.75° in both azimuth and elevation for simulation purposes

# Plotting the antenna pointing error: antenna pointing error is the difference of the real azimuth and elevation minus the azimuth and elevation of the antenna
```

Comment: Cool question and *nice script!* So you can search for passes and choose times when they are 1) the highest and/or 2) distance is minimum which means frequency shift due to Doppler is zero. Then you can choose your antenna trajectory to be zero error at those points at least.  If your antenna has a different beam width in different directions you can also calculate which passes are parallel to the broad direction and which parallel to the narrow direction OR you can optimize for closer to horizon when *rate of frequency shift* is lowest and angular speed is lowest which both make things easier

Comment: Typically, for ground station antennas, this is done using space radio sources and a calibration masts. Those. make a low-power transmitter with a simple antenna. drive the transmitter 5 kilometers from the antenna. From exactly known coordinates and mountain height, you can calculate the azimuth and altitude.